# Lipschitz functions preserve $F_{\sigma}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is true that if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a Lipschitz function, it is

> $\exists\,L\geq0, \forall\,x,y\in\mathbb{R}\,:\,\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|\leq L|x-y|$

then the image of a $F_{\sigma}$ set is $F_{\sigma}$?
($B\in F_{\sigma}$ if $B$ is a countable union of closed sets)

I guess is true but I cannot write $f(B)$ as a countable union of closed sets.

Comment: Can you write $B$ as a countable union of *compact* sets and use (only) continuity of $f?$

Comment: But, it is true that every closed set can be writed as a countable union of compact sets?

Comment: Consider the intersection of the closed set with the closed ball centered at the origin with radius $r,$ where $r$ takes on the values $1,$ $2,$ $3, \; \dots$ Note also that functions preserve unions (not necessarily intersections, but intersections don't matter here).